# Laravel Eloquent Many to Many Relationship between three Models

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

Consider I have the following table structures for tables `countries`, `products` and `suppliers`:

```
countries
------------------------
id
name
code
```

```
product
------------------------
id
name
price
```

```
suppliers
------------------------
id
name
```

A `product` can be sold in different `countries` but `supplier` of that `product` can be different. With that keeping in mind, I made a `relations` table to keep track of which `supplier` is delivering which `product` in which `country`:

```
relations
------------------------
country_id
product_id
supplier_id
```

Let's say I have a product `A` which I need to store in country `US` and `CA` but the suppliers for these countries are `X` and `Y` respectively. The structure would look something like this:

```
countries
-------------------------------
id    | name            | code
-------------------------------
1     | United States   | US
2     | Canada          | CA
```

```
product
-------------------------------
id    | name            | price
-------------------------------
1     | A               | 3.99
```

```
suppliers
------------
id    | name
------------
1     | X
2     | Y
```

```
relations
-------------------------------
country_id | product_id | supplier_id
-------------------------------
1          | 1          | 1
2          | 1          | 2
```

My question is how can I use Eloquent Relationships to this table since many-to-many relationships only work on two tables. Is there any other workaround regarding this? Or is there any other efficient way to implement this scenario?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Jerodev [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59152937/11418979), I made an intermediate model `SupplierProduct`. Instead of making many-to-many relationships, I made one-to-many relationships with `SupplierProduct` and retrieved data using `with` functions to retrieve all data related to that record.

This is how my Models look like (database structure is same as described in question):

**SupplierProduct.php**

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class SupplierProduct extends Model {

    public function country() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Country::class);
    }

    public function product() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Product::class);
    }

    public function supplier() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Supplier::class);
    }

}
```

**Country.php**

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Country extends Model {
    public function products() {
        return $this->hasMany(SupplierProduct::class)->with('product', 'supplier');
    }
}
```

**Product.php**

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Product extends Model {
    public function products() {
        return $this->hasMany(SupplierProduct::class)->with('country', 'supplier');
    }
}
```

**Supplier.php**

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Supplier extends Model {
    public function products() {
        return $this->hasMany(SupplierProduct::class)->with('country', 'product');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no built-in way to make a relation using three tables. Whenever I encounter something like this myself, the best solution seems to be to make an in-between model that has relations to the three tables.

So in your case, I would create a `SupplierProduct` that has the relations `country`, `supplier` and `product`.

Answer (score 0):

i have also same scenario class have multiple DaysClassDetails
use this function in your parent model

```
public function classType()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\DaysClassDetails(middlemodel)');
}
```

and DaysClassDetails have multiple DaysClassTimeDetails

```
public function classTime()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\DaysClassTimeDetails(lastchildmodel)');
}

public function classType(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\ManageClass(parentmodel)');
}
```